# Searching a string of free text for integers and return a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, search

I'm trying to search a list of strings for integers and return a list of tuples of the searched integers.

```
text = ['10 KM, REDUCING TO 6KM, IN PASSING SHOWERS', '10 KM, REDUCING TO 4000 M, IN PASSING SHOWERS', '2500M IN RAIN']
```

I've tried something like the following:

```
text_num = []

for i in text:
    for x in i:
        if x.isdigit() == True:
            text_num.append(x)
```

which returns:

```
text_num = ['1', '0', '6', '1', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '2', '5', '0', '0']
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be something like.

```
text_num = [(10, 6), (10, 4000), (2500)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
import re
[[int(num) for num in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', string)] 
 for string in text]
```

outputs

```
[[10, 6], [10, 4000], [2500]]
```